# upgrading Google.Cloud.Firestore API throws an error

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I posted this question in [GoogleCloudCommunity](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/upgrading-Google-Cloud-Firestore-API-throws-an-error/m-p/713865#M4928) but decided to post it here too.

Our **C# .Net Core** project is using **Google.Cloud.Firestore API version 2.5.0 and works just fine**.  However, the next version available is 3.0.0 and the latest is 3.5.1.  To take advantage of the new features or bug fixes I am trying to update it to the latest version but without a success.  Version 2.5.0 works flawlessly when we call **DocumentReference..SetAsync()** method but the moment I try to update the API to later or latest version I get this error.

> Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="**Error starting gRPC call**. HttpRequestException: **Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (proxy.domain.com:8080)** InvalidOperationException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (proxy.domain.com:8080)

[image]

What has changed in version 3.x and above and why is it not working in those versions?  How can I get around this error?

Comment: I checked your question in Google Cloud Community, do you still need help with your error?

Comment: @Marra no, I posted my answer but thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and forth and trying different things I was able to solve the problem.

It seems like **HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY environment variables** were needed prior to 3.x version but from 3.x onwards we no longer need these variables.

However, **do not delete them, rename them instead** because for some things like gcloud components updates you need them.  So, whenever you need them you rename them back and rename it again... I know it sucks but that is the only solution I have for now.